# aws S3 400 Bad Request

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm attempting to narrow down the following 400 Bad Request error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 7FBD3901B77A07C0), S3 Extended Request ID: +PrYXDrq9qJwhwHh+DmPusGekwWf+jmU2jepUkQX3zGa7uTT3GA1GlmHLkJjjjO67UQTndQA9PE=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1343)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:961)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:448)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:397)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:378)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4039)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1177)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1152)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesObjectExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1212)
    at com.abcnews.apwebfeed.articleresolver.APWebFeedArticleResolverImpl.makeS3Crops(APWebFeedArticleResolverImpl.java:904)
    at com.abcnews.apwebfeed.articleresolver.APWebFeedArticleResolverImpl.resolve(APWebFeedArticleResolverImpl.java:542)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.service.binding.ServiceInvocationHandler.sendMessage(ServiceInvocationHandler.java:322)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.service.binding.ServiceInvocationHandler$1.run(ServiceInvocationHandler.java:86)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I'm testing something as imple as this:

```
boolean exists = s3client.doesObjectExist("aws-wire-qa", "wfiles/in/wire.json");
```

I manually added the wfiles/in/wire.json file. I get back true when I run this line inside a local app. But inside a separate remote service it throws the error above. I use the same credentials inside the service as I use in my local app. I also set bucket as "Enable website hosting", but no difference. 
My permissions are set as:

```
Grantee: Any Authenticated AWS User
y List 
y Upload/DeleteView 
y PermissionsEdit Permissions
```

So I thought the error could be related to not having a policy on the bucket and created a policy file on the bucket for GET/PUT/DELETE objects, but I'm still getting the same error. My policy look like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1481303257155",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1481303250933",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::755710071517:user/law"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-wire-qa/*"
    }
]
}
```

I was told it can't be a firewall or a proxy issue. What else I could try? The error is very non-specific. And so far I did only local development, so I have no idea what else can be not set up here. Would much appreciate some help here.

Comment: This isn't related to permissions.  It's possible that you could be sending the request to the wrong S3 region.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: you are absolutely right, I was testing earlier with another bucket and managed not to change the region. Thanks a lot! Right on target!

Comment: Permissions issues were easily ruled out because that should be `403 Forbidden`... I'm glad that fixed it but, to be honest, that was just an intuitive guess -- one possibility among several that could cause a `400 Bad Request` response.  I would like to think that the Java SDK provides a mechanism to access the response headers and body, because the information should be there, and that would make for a more legitimate and useful answer.

Comment: I am not a Java developer, so I may have no idea what I'm asking, but I found [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/AmazonS3Exception.html), so I wonder... using that, is it possible for you to use `getErrorResponseXml()` to extract the error XML from the exception?

Comment: Locally installed the angular application which was running in another machine and tried executing `doesObjectExist`. It throws the same error mentioned in the question. 
I am using `app-dev.yml` properties file to fetch region and bucket name.
A Configuration File creates a Bean using which I check for `doesObjectExist`.
It works without an error using PostMan Tool, it throws error when I hit the same service using angular application. 
Is there something angular application should have? When I debug the java code in STS the region is same for both requests (via angular and Posstman).

Answer (score 9):

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/repo_s3' -d '{
      "type": "s3",
      "settings": {
        "bucket": "my-bucket",
        "base_path": "/folder/in/bucket",
        "region": "eu-central"     
      }
}'
```

In my case that was a region issue!
I had to remove the region from the elasticsearch.yml and set in the command. If I don't remove the region from the yml file, elastic won't start (with the latest s3-repository plugin)

```
Name: repository-s3
Description: The S3 repository plugin adds S3 repositories
Version: 5.2.2
 * Classname: org.elasticsearch.plugin.repository.s3.S3RepositoryPlugin
```

Comment: mine too was a region error, use fiddler to view their response as the .net exception is not clear.

Comment: Also region error for me, but interestingly enough the file still showed up fine in S3. Go figure.

Answer (score 5):

I have been getting this error for days, and in every case it was because my temporary access token had expired (or because I'd inadvertently built an instance of `hdfs-site.xml` containing an old token into a JAR). It had nothing to do with regions.

Answer (score 1):

Using Fiddler I've seen that my url was wrong.

I didn't need to use ServiceURL property and config class, instead, I used this constructor for the client, use your region as the third parameter.

```
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                ACCESSKEY,
                SECRETKEY,
                Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1
                );
```

Comment: I had an issue with `s3.getObject` in node.js - and it turns out the optional `region` parameter isn't truly optional. I was getting both a 400 response followed by a 200 response. This answer helped me locate the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same error and later found that this was due to an issue withe proxy setting. After disabling the proxy was able to upload to S3 fine.

```
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=s3***.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just to register my particular case...
I am configuring dspace to use S3. It is very clearly explained, but with region "eu-north-1" does not work. Error 400 is returned by Amazonaws.

Create a bucket test with us-west-1 (by default) , and try.

Answer (score -2):

Bucket policy

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

CORS policy

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*",
            "https://yourwebsite.com" //Optional
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Comment: That bucket policy is not "AllowPublicRead". It's allow everything.